# Add custom tax calculating using custom API in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, tax

Researched Shopify API reference but didn't get any solution yet. I am looking to add a custom Tax (calculated from third party API) in Shopify on checkout page.

I knew that Shopify does not allow to customize checkout page and we have checked the API reference also but its not helpful.

Is there any alternate way to calculate the tax from third party API in Shopify?

Answer (score 0):

No. Since you do not control pricing in any way, shape or form, if the tax is not injected via some approved Shopify partner (like Avalara), you're out of luck. You could use Draft Orders as with a draft you can do anything you want with tax, but that is not practical for customers.

Comment: Can you please share more details on Draft Orders?